# Visual Studio C# - Settings files from multiple library to App.config in main project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, configuration-files, application-settings

I have library projects A, B, and C and executable projects X and Y. Projects A, B, and C have their own Settings.setting files and X and Y each have their own App.configs

Let's say X uses A and B and Y uses A and C. IS there any way I can make the App.configs to link to the Settings.settings of the referenced libraries and auto-generate tags based on the properties in those Settings files?

I remember I was once able to do this in a previous company but I forgot how that was set up.